# What does a colon ':' mean in a formula field?

Tags: formula-field

I have a formula field on the case object like this:

```
IF( ISBLANK( Owner:Queue.OwnerId ), Owner:User.FirstName & " " & Owner:User.LastName, Owner:Queue.QueueName)
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Owner` is a polymorphic lookup field, which means that you can put there `User` and `Queue` values, `Owner:Queue` says that "treat Owner field value as Queue SObject"